# What is the formula for the homology class represented by the diagonal?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, homology, gromov-witten-theory, symplectic-topology

Let $M$ be a compact oriented manifold and $\{\mu_{i}\}$ a basis 
for the homology $H_*(M, \mathbb{Z})$ (we are ignoring any torsion). 
Now consider the diagonal $\Delta_{M}$ inside $M\times M$. Suppose 
we write it as 
$$ \Delta_{M} = \sum g^{ij} \mu_i \times \mu_j \in H_*(M \times M, \mathbb{Z}).$$
My question is, what are these $g^{ij}$? Based on reading one paper, it seems to  me the following ought to be true (but I do not actually see why this is so):

Let 
$$ g_{ij} := \mu_i \cdot \mu_j, $$ 
where $\cdot$ is the topological intersection. And then it seems to me 
$$ g^{ij} := (g^{-1})_{ij}. $$ 
Is this some standard/obvious fact? The paper I am referring to is 
"Mathematical theory of Quantum Cohomology" by Ruan and Tian

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214457234

End of page 262 and beginning of page 263 has the relevant discussion 
(I am using a slightly different notation from them).

Comment: It is indeed a very standard (and easy) fact; it is usually stated in cohomology, but this is equivalent through Poincaré duality. One reference (among many) is Milnor-Stasheff, *Characteristic classes*, Thm. 11.11.

Comment: For the dual statement, see Example 7.3.9, p. 249 of the notes below. http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf

Comment: @abx and Liviu: Thanks; this answers my question.